# How to use DatePicker in NativeScript dialogs

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a `DatePicker` in one of `NativeScript/Angular` App like below.

```
<StackLayout class="m-x-10 form" [formGroup]="myForm">
<DockLayout stretchLastChild="true">
        <Label text="Date" class="m-x-auto m-y-auto" dock="left"></Label>
        <StackLayout class="input-field">
          <DatePicker loaded="onDatePickerLoaded" formControlName="transDate" minDate="{{ minDate }}" maxDate="{{ maxDate }}"></DatePicker>
        </StackLayout>
      </DockLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I want to show DatePicker on dialogs and assign result to a formgroup property some thing like below.

```
<TextField formControlName="transDate" (tap)="showDatePicker()"></TextField>

showDatePicker() {
    let options = {
      title: "Transaction Date",
      message: "Select Date",
      cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
      actions: // need to show DatePicker here
    };
    action(options).then((result) => {
      if (result !== 'Cancel') {
        this.myForm.controls['transDate'].setValue(result);
      }
    });
  }
```

How do I do it?

As @Manoj suggested adding `tns plugin add nativescript-modal-datetimepicker` and moving its files to app folder and importing from new path is working as I expected.

Now I changed `<item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>` in  `App_Resources/Android/values-21/styles.xml` as per doc but still showing spinner only.

Comment: You can use ngModel with DatePicker in dialogs and the assign the result to a formgroup property.

Comment: Any example link please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [nativescript-modal-datetimepicker](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-modal-datetimepicker) plugin

```
tns plugin add nativescript-modal-datetimepicker
```

Comment: It's not available in preview app, so every time running tns run android --build and taking apk file to mobile is time consuming activity. That's why I am looking for alternative.

Comment: The plugin doesn't use any native dependency, so it should be compatible with Playground. Just that you will have to import with relative path.

Comment: Plugin nativescript-modal-datetimepicker is not included in preview app on device b4d842bc-7e13-4e56-ac8b-de5eb0a8f103 and will not work.

Comment: I'm sure about what I'm saying. You can include the plugin files within project and just import it with relative path.

Comment: Understood and working now with spinner but not calendar. Do I need to do any extra bit for this?

Comment: Which version of Android you are using?

Comment: "nativescript-angular": "~7.2.0", "@angular/core": "~7.2.0"

Comment: I had asked Android, not Angular. What is your OS version on your device.

Comment: Sorry, OS version: Android 7.1.2

Comment: By default it should be calendar, try setting `datePickerMode` to `calendar` as described in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are coming to this thread 2 years later, it's a much better option to use NativeScript's official date picker:

https://github.com/NativeScript/plugins/tree/main/packages/datetimepicker

I made the mistake of trying the nativescript-modal-datetimepicker plugin first, unfortunately it crashes on iOS 14 and the author doesn't seem to be actively fixing issues.

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have created sample for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=JcHXHl).
You need to use [custom Dialog](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/dialogs#showing-custom-dialog).

And in ShowPicker function()

```
let options: ModalDialogOptions = {
            viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef
        };

       this.modalService.showModal(DialogContent, options)
    .then((dialogResult: string) => {
 this.myForm.controls['transDate'].setValue(result);
 this.result = dialogResult})
```

You can pass the selected Date in close call back.

Comment: I just added console.error(dialogResult); to your playground link, as there is not OK, Cancel button visible, result is always undefined. Here is the link https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=JcHXHl&v=2

Comment: That was just the example to show how you should proceed. Key is to use Custom Dialog and pass the information back in close callback.